# What is this orange selection on enemies in the Witcher 3

Tags: the-witcher-3

Since I've been playing the Witcher's DLCs I am frequently bumping into the issue where I am 'locked on' to an enemy, shown by the orange border on the level of the enemy. (But I'm not entirely sure it only occurs in the DLCs.) I think I do this by pressing a key combination by accident. What happens, then, is that Geralt starts moving around by himself. He also casts Axii without me telling him to.

I haven't found how to turn this off. Reloading a save game does not stop it, but restarting the entire game does. What is this and how can I turn it off? What is the key combination for it?

[image: Orange selection]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the Lock On Target indicator which is activated with <kbd>R3</kbd> on the PS4 and I believe <kbd>Z</kbd> on the PC. When this is active Geralt will focus on attacking a single target. Just press the key / button again to switch back to normal mode.

Comment: And what does it do exactly? He'll automatically move around target and cast spells. Anything else?

Comment: On the PS4 I haven't seen this automatic movement or casting of spells. It just means all his attacks are focused on the one enemy. But I don't use this much.

Comment: Hm, maybe I accidentally pressed another key combination as well. I'll investigate.